# How to get all ticket's short description from virtual task board card with Table API in Service Now

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I'm trying to build a virtual task board with Service Now table api, which contains lands, ticket number, and ticket short description

Using this api, I can retrieve ticket number, lands, but not ticket short description:

```
https://dev29624.service-now.com/api/now/table/vtb_card?sysparm_display_value=all&sysparm_limit=1
```

How can I retrieve ticket short description without calling another api to retrieve it? The large number of tickets may result in bad performance!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by dot-walking with the `sysparm_fields` query parameter.

```
task.number,task.short_description
```

Example:

```
GET https://<instance name>.service-now.com/api/now/table/vtb_card?sysparm_fields=task.number%2C%20task.short_description&sysparm_limit=1
```

Reference: https://developer.servicenow.com/blog.do?p=/post/dot-walking-in-the-rest-table-api-2/